# Android WorkManager: Is it possible to set task's maximum execution duration

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I have a periodic task that requesting location updates on the background, but I need to restrict this task too work for a long period of time, as it will drain battery, so I need to stop it after a few minutes (3 min). Does Work Manager provide some mechanism to restrict the task's execution time ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just set Constraints so that your task won't run if battery is low? See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#work-constraints

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WorkManager doesn't have this functionality.
There's a hard limit of 10 minutes when running a Worker and then the OS is going to stop the worker (this is possible to overcome promoting a Worker to a foreground service as described on the blog: [Use WorkManager for immediate background execution](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution-a57db502603d)).

If you want to implement a timeout of 3 minutes you need to implement it in your worker.

Using Kotlin and CoroutineWorker this can be implemented using [`withTimeout`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-timeout.html) over the block of code that you want to run with a time limit:

```
class MyWorker(
    appContext: Context,
    private val params: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {

  override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    return withTimeout(3 * 60 * 1000) {
      // Do a long computation
      // ...
      return@withTimeout Result.success()
    }
  }
}
```